# Is it possible to replicate a network interface?

Tags: networking

I have an interface eth0, is it possible to replicate it in an eth1 one?
I'd like for my system to believe it has two network interfaces while it has actually one

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible and actually quite straightforward. It is widely used to serve multiple websites from one physical server. Google "virtual interfaces" or see e.g. [here](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux) . The virtual interface can work with or without DHCP independently from the real one. Only it wouldn't be called eth1 but rather eth0:0, in your case.